# A software to test a Blockchain-based model

Tags: programming

I want a software to simulate a blockchain-based model for something which I cannot tell since it is a research project. The model has smart contracts (ideally should be written in solidity), validator nodes, A centralized server, and a front-end web application that should call the smart contract via a web API. It should also use the proof-of-stake (PoS) consensus algorithm.

After developing I want to test my simulated model by executing various attack scenarios like DoS (Denial of Service), sniffing, etc. on a specific set of validator nodes to measure the fault-tolerance and attack resistance.

I have a Windows 10 machine with 8GB RAM and an Intel CORE i7 processor. I would prefer a windows compatible, easy to use, GUI-based software.